# Solution procedure for poisson equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

Consider the Poisson equation in the rectangle $Q=\{(x,y):0<x<1,0<y<1\}$,

> $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=F(x,y)$$
>   $$u(0,y)=0,\,u(1,y)=0$$
>   $$u(x,0)=\phi(x),\,\,u(x,1)=\psi(x)$$

**My Question**: Is my solution procedure correct?

**Solution Procedure**:

I apply Fourier method. The corresponding auxiliary problem is 
$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$$
$$X(0)=0, \, X(1)=0.$$
The eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2,\,\,X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x),\,n=1,2,\ldots.$$

Expansion of $F(x,y),\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ in terms of eigenfunctions are 
$$F(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(y)\sin(n\pi x),$$
$$\phi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi_n\sin(n\pi x),$$
$$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\psi_n\sin(n\pi x),$$
where $$f_n(y)=2\int\limits_0^1F(x,y)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$
$$\phi_n=2\int\limits_0^1\phi(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$
and $$\psi_n=2\int\limits_0^1\psi(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx,\,n=1,2,\ldots.$$
I assume that the solution is in the following form
$$u(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(y)\sin(n\pi x),$$
where $a_n(y),n=1,2,...$ are solutions of 
$$a_n^{''}-n^2\pi^2a_n(y)=f_n(y)$$
$$a_n(0)=\phi_n,\,a_n(1)=\psi_n,$$
$\,n=1,2,\ldots.$

Comment: Everything looks good to me at a first glance, but why is there a 2 in front of the definitions of  $f_n, \phi_n$ and $\psi_n$?